# Is it possible to access column names within pandas groupby transform?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My ideal question would be "How to access columns in pandas DataFrameGroupBy.transform?", but after performing some tests (herein showed), I wonder if that's even possible.

I would like to access column names just like I can do with `apply`, but using `transform` instead.

For example, given this sample data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)
numeric_data = np.random.rand(9, 3)
cat_data = [f'grp_{i}' for i in range(1,4)] * 3
df = pd.DataFrame(numeric_data, columns=list('ABC')).assign(D = cat_data)
print(df)
```

```
          A         B         C      D
0  0.696469  0.286139  0.226851  grp_1
1  0.551315  0.719469  0.423106  grp_2
2  0.980764  0.684830  0.480932  grp_3
3  0.392118  0.343178  0.729050  grp_1
4  0.438572  0.059678  0.398044  grp_2
5  0.737995  0.182492  0.175452  grp_3
6  0.531551  0.531828  0.634401  grp_1
7  0.849432  0.724455  0.611024  grp_2
8  0.722443  0.322959  0.361789  grp_3
```

How can I use `transform` to subtract B from A, then multiply by C? Is it possible?
I know that with *apply* I can easily achieve that by using *lambda* or passing a user-defined function, like this:

```py
def customFunc(grp):
    return (grp['A'] - grp['B']) * grp['C']

df.groupby('D').apply(customFunc)
```

```
D       
grp_1  0    0.093084
       3    0.035679
       6   -0.000175
grp_2  1   -0.071147
       4    0.150817
       7    0.076364
grp_3  2    0.142324
       5    0.097464
       8    0.144529
dtype: float64
```

The output values, though, it's unsorted (as you can see in the internal index) so that I can't just place this output as it is in a new column. An option would be sorting the dataframe before-hand using apply, but to be honest I'm not fully confident it would work as expected for large data with more complex groups in groupby. I would feel more comfortable using transform, otherwise, I think it's more reliable to merge the result back to the df by index (supposing we have a unique index).

If I try to use the same function with transform:

```
df.groupby('D').transform(customFunc)
```

then I get an error: `KeyError: 'A'`.

To inspect what's going on under the hood when using `groupby.apply` and `groupby.transform`, I did the following:

```py
# Select the target-group
grp = df.groupby('D')

grp.apply(lambda x: type(x))

D
grp_1    (<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, 3)
grp_2    (<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, 3)
grp_3    (<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, 3)
dtype: object

grp.transform(lambda x: type(x))
                                     A                                    B                                    C  
0  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  
1  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  
2  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  
3  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  
4  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  
5  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  
6  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  
7  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  
8  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>  <property object at 0x7f7dbde619f0>
```

As you can see, `apply` provide us sub-dataframes as groups, while I don't know exactly what `transform` does provide (it's the first time I've faced a property). I also have done further tests:

```py
# Another trials
grp.transform(lambda x: x.shape) # ValueError
grp.transform(lambda x: x['A']) # KeyError
grp.transform(lambda x: x.loc[0]) # KeyError
grp.transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0]) # works (every value get the first value; similar to 'first')
```

It seems that with `.iloc[]` I can access the values for each column independently, but I still couldn't figure how to access the columns within `transform` (if it's even possible).

So, my final questions:

- Is it possible to access column names in `groupby.transform` to perform calculation across columns?
- If not, what's the best (reliable) way to place the output from `apply` back to the dataframe?

Comment: In your first example, why do you need to group by D if you're just operating columns elementwise and appending the result back to the dataframe? You could do that with `df["result"] = (df["B"] - df["A"])*df["C"]`. Could you show an example in which grouping is actually needed?

Comment: You're right! I did not provide a good example for this. But just imagine we replace `* C` by `* np.mean(C)` to grouping make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to access column names in groupby.transform to perform calculation across columns?

Not possible, `.groupby.transform` working with each column separately, so cannot 'see' another columns like `groupby.apply`.

You can see it if use `print`:

```
print (df.groupby('D').transform(lambda x: print(x)))
2    0.980764
5    0.737995
8    0.722443
Name: A, dtype: float64
2    0.684830
5    0.182492
8    0.322959
Name: B, dtype: float64
2    0.480932
5    0.175452
8    0.361789
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

> If not, what's the best (reliable) way to place the output from apply back to the dataframe?

If function not aggregate values:

```
def customFunc(grp):
    return (grp['A'] - grp['B']) * grp['C']

df['new'] = df.groupby('D').apply(customFunc).rename('new').reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

print (df)
          A         B         C      D       new
0  0.696469  0.286139  0.226851  grp_1  0.093084
1  0.551315  0.719469  0.423106  grp_2 -0.071147
2  0.980764  0.684830  0.480932  grp_3  0.142324
3  0.392118  0.343178  0.729050  grp_1  0.035679
4  0.438572  0.059678  0.398044  grp_2  0.150817
5  0.737995  0.182492  0.175452  grp_3  0.097464
6  0.531551  0.531828  0.634401  grp_1 -0.000175
7  0.849432  0.724455  0.611024  grp_2  0.076364
8  0.722443  0.322959  0.361789  grp_3  0.144529
```

so working same like:

```
df['new'] = (df['A'] - df['B']) * df['C']

print (df)
         A         B         C      D       new
0  0.696469  0.286139  0.226851  grp_1  0.093084
1  0.551315  0.719469  0.423106  grp_2 -0.071147
2  0.980764  0.684830  0.480932  grp_3  0.142324
3  0.392118  0.343178  0.729050  grp_1  0.035679
4  0.438572  0.059678  0.398044  grp_2  0.150817
5  0.737995  0.182492  0.175452  grp_3  0.097464
6  0.531551  0.531828  0.634401  grp_1 -0.000175
7  0.849432  0.724455  0.611024  grp_2  0.076364
8  0.722443  0.322959  0.361789  grp_3  0.144529
```

If function aggregate values use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) if one column is used for grouping:

```
def customFunc(grp):
    return ((grp['A'] - grp['B']) * grp['C']).mean()

df = df.join(df.groupby('D').apply(customFunc).rename('new'), on='D')
```

---

```
def customFunc(grp):
    return ((grp['A'] - grp['B']) * grp['C']).mean()

df['new'] = df['D'].map(df.groupby('D').apply(customFunc))


print (df)
       A         B         C      D       new
0  0.696469  0.286139  0.226851  grp_1  0.042863
1  0.551315  0.719469  0.423106  grp_2  0.052011
2  0.980764  0.684830  0.480932  grp_3  0.128106
3  0.392118  0.343178  0.729050  grp_1  0.042863
4  0.438572  0.059678  0.398044  grp_2  0.052011
5  0.737995  0.182492  0.175452  grp_3  0.128106
6  0.531551  0.531828  0.634401  grp_1  0.042863
7  0.849432  0.724455  0.611024  grp_2  0.052011
8  0.722443  0.322959  0.361789  grp_3  0.128106
```

Or change function:

```
def customFunc(grp):
    grp['new'] = ((grp['A'] - grp['B']) * grp['C']).mean()
    return grp
    
df = df.groupby('D').apply(customFunc)

print (df)
          A         B         C      D       new
0  0.696469  0.286139  0.226851  grp_1  0.042863
1  0.551315  0.719469  0.423106  grp_2  0.052011
2  0.980764  0.684830  0.480932  grp_3  0.128106
3  0.392118  0.343178  0.729050  grp_1  0.042863
4  0.438572  0.059678  0.398044  grp_2  0.052011
5  0.737995  0.182492  0.175452  grp_3  0.128106
6  0.531551  0.531828  0.634401  grp_1  0.042863
7  0.849432  0.724455  0.611024  grp_2  0.052011
8  0.722443  0.322959  0.361789  grp_3  0.128106
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @jezrael! I really appreciate this (actually, all of your answers). Just to make sure I understand correctly: in your first code chunk at "If function not aggregate values:", does pandas automatically sort the values to match the index from the Series with the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on @jezrael's answer:

> > Is it possible to access column names in `groupby.transform` to perform calculation across columns?
>
> Not possible, `.groupby.transform` working with each column separately, so cannot 'see' another columns like `groupby.apply`.

This is because of how `transform` is [specified](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) (emphases mine):

> Notes
>
> ---
>
> Each group is endowed the attribute 'name' in case you need to know which group you are working on.
>
> The current implementation imposes three requirements on f:
>
> - f must return a value that either has the same shape as the input   subframe or can be broadcast to the shape of the input subframe.   For
>   example, if `f` returns a scalar it will be broadcast to have the
>   same shape as the input subframe.
> - if this is a DataFrame, f **must support application column-by-column**   in the subframe. **If f also supports application to the entire
>   subframe,   then a fast path is used starting from the second chunk**.
> - f must not mutate groups. Mutation is not supported and may   produce unexpected results.

I.e. it requires the function to be able to work on individual columns. But *if* it works for an entire dataframe, `pandas` automatically switches to applying on entire groups midway (seems a bit kludgy to me, but whatever). Again, we can see this using `print` in our transform function:

```py
def f(x):
    print(x.name, type(x))
    return x
```

```
In [1]: gb.transform(f)
A <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
A <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
B <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
C <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
grp_1 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
grp_2 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
grp_3 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Out[1]:
          A         B         C
0  0.696469  0.286139  0.226851
1  0.551315  0.719469  0.423106
2  0.980764  0.684830  0.480932
3  0.392118  0.343178  0.729050
4  0.438572  0.059678  0.398044
5  0.737995  0.182492  0.175452
6  0.531551  0.531828  0.634401
7  0.849432  0.724455  0.611024
8  0.722443  0.322959  0.361789
```

Here we can see what `pandas` is doing internally:

- first, a "trial run" on the first column, `A` (not really sure what this is doing, but it's probably to see if the function is compatible or what method to use for best performance);
- then it applies `f` column by column on the first group (`grp_1`);
- once it realises that `f` works on an entire dataframe (I'm guessing by trying `f` on the first group again and then comparing with the column-by-column result), it switches to applying `f` to each group everything at once, as whole dataframes.

In fact, knowing this it is actually possible to extract the columns *starting from the second part of the algorithm* (once it starts applying on entire dataframes):

```py
def f(x):
    try:
        x["A"]
        print(x.name, type(x), "column retrieval succeeded")
    except KeyError:
        print(x.name, type(x), "column retrieval failed")
    return x
```

```
In [59]: gb.transform(f)
A <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> column retrieval failed
A <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> column retrieval failed
B <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> column retrieval failed
C <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> column retrieval failed
grp_1 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> column retrieval succeeded
grp_2 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> column retrieval succeeded
grp_3 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> column retrieval succeeded
Out[59]:
          A         B         C
0  0.696469  0.286139  0.226851
1  0.551315  0.719469  0.423106
2  0.980764  0.684830  0.480932
3  0.392118  0.343178  0.729050
4  0.438572  0.059678  0.398044
5  0.737995  0.182492  0.175452
6  0.531551  0.531828  0.634401
7  0.849432  0.724455  0.611024
8  0.722443  0.322959  0.361789
```

Of course, this isn't useful in practice, as the transform function, as specified in the documentation, should be able to work on individual columns (and *optionally* entire dataframes), so you shouldn't be referring to specific columns in this function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Indeed, the print statements helped me to understand it better. I've been struggling to understand how  `transform` works. In the end, it looks like I was looking for doing something I was not supposed to do haha.